# Actual global error vs theoretical global error: How to combine theory with practice

Tags: finite-difference, ode, error-estimation, numerics, differential-equations

I have implemented an Adams Bashforth 4 method to solve an Initial Value Problem for an ODE and I am testing it against the test equation:

$y'=\lambda y$ with $y(0)=1$ with the exact solution: $y(t)=e^{\lambda t}$.
I have set $\lambda =1$.

I get decent results and decent rate of convergence because the loglog plot is linear with slope of 4 (AD4 is of order 4 so the error is $O(h^4)$). Here is the global error when I am testing it in the interval $t \in [0,3]$
[image]

**Is this consistent with theory?** Also, **where will you plot the $O(h^4)-$line in this graph?** I know it needs to be parallel to the AD4 line but where? In general, **I don't really know the connection between the global error and $O(h^4)$**

Here is my data

```
h        = ( 0.1, 0.05, 0.01, 0.005)
ad4error = (3.477e-03, 2.493e-04, 4.445e-07, 2.816e-08)
```

Comment: "I'm a self-learner so I don't read books." 

*proceeds to post question on SE*.

Not making fun of you but I found this amusing!

Comment: There is no substitute for books. Writing books requires a massive effort and forces the author to review, revise and extend her presentation of all subjects and how they interact. Order books through your public library

Comment: You want to use a slope triangle and to position it close to the curve representing our actual data. This way you will be able to show the order of growth of the error in a compact and easily comprehensible manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to turn my comment into an answer.

The error order tells you up to which order (exclusive) the discrete
solution corresponds to the exact solution.

An $\mathcal{O}(\Delta t^4)$ method reproduces the orders 0-3 of the Taylor expansion of the
function around $\Delta t$ (i.e. in the expression $f(t+\Delta t) = f(t) +\dots$).

Put bluntly (and mathematically imprecisely)
if you halve the size of the time step $\Delta t$ the deviation will be smaller by $2^4$.
This, of course, assumes that the error is computed at the same final time.
Or, if you want to use the log-log plot effectively you can say that by reducing 
the step size by one order of magnitude $\Delta t = 10^{-1} \rightarrow \Delta t = 10^{-2}$
the deviation from the analytic solution will be reduced by 4 orders of magnitude, i.e.,
instead of $10^{-2}$ it will be $10^{-6}$.

To visualize the growth of an error one could plot curves of different orders ($\Delta  t^2, \Delta t^3$ etc.)
and try and compare the result to these curves. This is very finnicky in a log-log plot and
results in a rather confusing plot.
A better way is to define a function that will draw a slope triangle with appropriately
labelled sides close to the curve(s) you want to show the behaviour of.

I have used this in the analysis of the implementation of $\mathcal{P}_2,\mathcal{P}_3$ 
finite elements in my thesis, as can be seen in the following plot.

[image: Finite element errors for a Poisson equation on a rectangle, using different FE orders.]

Note that this plot would be really confusing if I were to add an entire curve for each growth order. Admittedly, the slope triangles could have been placed better, but they do show the growth order (one power of $2$ of mesh width corresponds to $n$ powers of $10$ on the error axis).

Comment: To be honest your excellent answer is way beyond what I am asking for. I don't have the theoritical knowledge to follow you 100%. The global error for a method of order $p$ is bounded such that $|E_N|\ \leq Ch^p$. I am basically asking how to find that $C$ constant and plot the line on the graph shown in my post

Comment: If you want an empirical constant just divide the computed error for a given step-size by the step-size and take the maximum of the results, e.g. $max_i\lbrace \frac{|E(h_i)|}{h_i}\rbrace$. To plot a simple line (I advise against that) is then to simply generate $y_i = C\cdot h_i$ with the constant you obtained and the step-sizes $h_i$ and then plot it against $h_i$.

Comment: Let's I find $C$ the way you have described here. Then I use this *method/solver* on a NEW IV problem, let's say: $y'=y*sin(t)$ and I find values for $y$ for a given $h$. Is it hen **fair** to say that my error is bounded such that is is $Ch^4$ at the most? I might not have been clear with my question but that is basically what I try estimate with the $O(h^p)$ error as I described. Thank you very much for your help so far by the way

Comment: The constant is implicitly dependent upon the equation. For each problem you'll find a different constant. But once you've found a constant *for a particular equation* then the estimate will likely be true *for that specific equation*.